# Why does Wolfram Alpha get this domain wrong?

Tags: functions, wolfram-alpha

I wanted to check on *Wolfram* if the domain of
$\dfrac{\log |x|}{\arctan \left(x\right)\left(x-2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ I calculated was correct.

According to *Wolfram* it is $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x>2 \}$

I put the function into *Desmos* and the plot shows that in $0$ and $2 $ the function diverges, as I had calculated myself.

Why doesn't *WA* show that?

Comment: Use `cbrt()` instead of $(x-2)^{1/3}$, the last gives the principal cube root which is complex

Comment: @gammatester It works using $cbrt()$. Thanks. I will use it from now on.

Comment: @Masacroso: WA is close to being perfect. When plotting the function, it gives you a choice between two conventions. I keep being shocked by negative opinions on this extraordinary and *free* CAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram can use two conventions for the cubic root: principal or real-valued. The former returns a complex number, which can be ruled out.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the `cube root`, which exists for all real numbers and the function $x^{1/3}$, which is defined only for $x>0$, as its definition is 
$$x^{1/3}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\mathrm e^{\tfrac13\ln x}.$$